# Capital letter after title of incollection item ending in question mark using biblatex' ieee-style

Tags: biblatex, capitalization, ieee-style

I noticed that the *in* after a title in a bibliography entry of an `@incollection`-type is capitalised, whenever the entry title ends in a `?` or a `!`. It is not capitalised in any other case. This looks a bit odd and somewhat inconsistent (although it is technically not of course).

Is there a way to change this behaviour to be either all capitalised or all non-capitalised?

Here is an MWE reproducing this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex} % 
\bibliography{bibliography}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
    @incollection{example1,
        author = {Doe, John},
        title = {Title without question mark},
        editor = {editor},
        booktitle = {Book title},
        year = {2009}
    }
    @incollection{example2,
        author = {Doe, Jane},
        title = {Title with a question mark?},
        editor = {editor},
        booktitle = {Book title},
        year = {2009}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` has a punctuation tracker that tries to avoid awkward double punctuation. Here the question mark and following comma would create double punctuation, so `biblatex` suppresses the comma and then capitalises the "In" after the question mark.

There are several ways around this. One option is to allow the double punctuation.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*?!}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{example1,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  title     = {Title without question mark},
  editor    = {editor},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  year      = {2009},
}
@incollection{example2,
  author    = {Doe, Jane},
  title     = {Title with a question mark?},
  editor    = {editor},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  year      = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: J. Doe, ‘Title with a question mark?,’ in Book title, editor, Ed., 2009.]

Another option would be to hide the question mark from the punctuation tracker with `\@`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{example1,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  title     = {Title without question mark},
  editor    = {editor},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  year      = {2009},
}
@incollection{example2,
  author    = {Doe, Jane},
  title     = {Title with a question mark?\@},
  editor    = {editor},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  year      = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: J. Doe, ‘Title with a question mark?,’ in Book title, editor, Ed., 2009.]

Finally, you can force the "in" to stay lowercase at all times while still suppressing the comma

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \bibncpstring{in}%
  \printunit{\intitlepunct}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{example1,
  author    = {Doe, John},
  title     = {Title without question mark},
  editor    = {editor},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  year      = {2009},
}
@incollection{example2,
  author    = {Doe, Jane},
  title     = {Title with a question mark?},
  editor    = {editor},
  booktitle = {Book title},
  year      = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: J. Doe, ‘Title with a question mark?’ in Book title, editor, Ed., 2009.]