# Article title ending with question mark

Tags: biblatex

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
style=numeric,
giveninits=true,
sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Title?},
  year = {2021},
  journal = {Journal}
}

@article{key2,
  author = {Author, B.},
  title = {Title},
  year = {2021},
  journal = {Journal}
}
 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}, \cite{key2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

It can be seen that the title ending with question mark doesn't have a period after the quote symbols, while the one without question mark has a period. Is it possible to add a period in titles ending with quotation mark?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker, which is supposed to avoid undesirable double punctuation, at work. Normally that feature avoids punctuation clashes caused by field values and `biblatex`-generated punctuation doubling up.

Here it could be argued that the feature goes to far, especially because the quotation marks provide a visual barrier that separates the double punctuation.

Solution one would be to 'hide' the question mark from `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker. Either directly in the `.bib` entry with `\@` after the `?`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  giveninits=true,
  sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  title   = {Title?\@},
  year    = {2021},
  journal = {Journal},
}
@article{key2,
  author  = {Author, B.},
  title   = {Title},
  year    = {2022},
  journal = {Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{key1,key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A. Author. “Title?”. In: Journal (2021).]

or globally in all `title` fields that are wrapped in quotation marks with suitable redefinitions of the field format that add the `\@`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  giveninits=true,
  sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}

%\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\@}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\@}}
%\DeclareFieldFormat
%  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
%  {title}{#1\@}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  title   = {Title?},
  year    = {2021},
  journal = {Journal},
}
@article{key2,
  author  = {Author, B.},
  title   = {Title},
  year    = {2022},
  journal = {Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{key1,key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A. Author. “Title?”. In: Journal (2021).]

Another solution would be to generally allow question marks and exclamation marks to be followed by a period. But this may lead to undesirable punctuation clashes in situations where there are no quotation marks or where they are not desired for other reasons. (For more on `\DeclarePunctuationPairs` see [Biblatex punctuation recognition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428478/35864.))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric,
  giveninits=true,
  sorting=nyt,
]{biblatex}

\DeclarePunctuationPairs{period}{.?!}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key1,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  title   = {Title?},
  year    = {2021},
  journal = {Journal},
}
@article{key2,
  author  = {Author, B.},
  title   = {Title},
  year    = {2022},
  journal = {Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{key1,key2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

See also the recent [Capital letter after title of incollection item ending in question mark using biblatex' ieee-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597585/35864).